# How can I find HTML like tags in a string using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, tags, extract

I have the following string:

```
var originalStr = "Test example <firstTag>text inside first tag</firstTag>, <secondTag>50</secondTag> end."
```

What's the best way to identify all tags, the correspondent tag name and their content? This is the kind of result I'm looking for.

```js
var tagsFound = 
    [ { "tagName": "firstTag",  "value": "text inside first tag" } 
    , { "tagName": "secondTag", "value": "50" } 
    ]
```

Comment: There are [dozens of questions](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+%5Bnodejs%5D+parse+html) covering this topic on the site, I suggest looking through them. But I've also included some information below (many of those questions are fairly specific and also quite old).

Comment: https://bun.sh/docs/bundler/macros#make-fetch-requests-at-bundle-time Thank you everyone guys, i found a built in that does just what i wanted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on complexity of strings you dealing with - the simple regEx solution might work (it works for your string nicely:

```js
var str = 'Test example <firstTag>text inside first tag</firstTag>, <secondTag>50</secondTag> end.';

var tagsFound = [];
str.replace(/<([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/\1>/g, function(m,m1,m2){
    // write data to result objcect
    tagsFound.push({
        "tagName": m1,
        "value": m2
    })
    // replace with original = do nothing with string
    return m;
});

// Displaying the results
for(var i=0;i<tagsFound.length; i++){
    console.log(tagsFound[i]);
}
```

There will be a problem when self closing tags or tags containing other tags are taken into accont. Like `<selfClosedTag/>` or `<tag><tag>something</tag>else</tag>`

Comment: Can you explain how did you get the m1 and m2 values with the regex?

Answer (score 2):

HTML is **very** complicated to parse, so the best approach is to use a parser that already exists.

If you're doing this in a browser, you can use the one built into the browser: [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

If you're doing this in Node.js, there are several libraries to do it, such as [`jsdom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom). It provides an API almost identical to the one in web browsers.

Here's a `jsdom` example:

```
const dom = new JSDOM("<!doctype html>" + originalStr);
const doc = dom.window.document;
for (const childElement of doc.body.children) {
    console.log(`${childElement.tagName} - ${childElement.textContent}`);
}
```

With your string, that would output:

```
FIRSTTAG - text inside first tag
SECONDTAG - 50
```

You'd write code using the DOM methods provided to create the output you're looking for. (Note the tag name normalization above; you may have to use [`nodeLocation`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom#getting-the-source-location-of-a-node-with-nodelocationnode) to get the original capitalization if it matters to what you're doing.)